# Originally fast queries with index go much slower if repeated after executing another slow queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB, NodeJs with mongoose. I have a big database with 7.5 million documents. There is an `url` field and an index on it `{ url: 1 }`.

My first query is like:

```
Scheme.find({ url: { $regex: "^google\.com.*" } }).limit(50).sort({ _id: -1 }).exec()

(the url values go without http/https, so it is a check for a values starts-with)
```

Execution takes about 0.04 seconds.

Ok, go further: now search for something like:

```
{ $regex: "^.*google\.com.*" }
```

it took 105 seconds because the beginning of string in the regex is `.*` and the index was not helpful.

Ok, it's ok.

But the problem is:
now I repeat the first query (`^google\.com.*`), and the search takes 40-50 seconds

Then I just restart mongod and it takes again less than 0.1 s

Couldn't find the reason of such behaviour :(

Also did

```
Scheme.find({ url: { $regex: "^google\.com.*" } }).limit(50).sort({ _id: -1 }).explain()
```

results did not differ for slow and fast queries, just in `result[0].executionStats.executionTimeMillis`: 1 for fast vs 15 for slow

P.S.
serverStatus after first query quick passing: https://gist.github.com/crystalbit/4e7919ddd822c0fbbf2dfc2bbad7195b

serverStatus after second query (legally slow): https://gist.github.com/crystalbit/6a3687784a6f982e3459bc400f2d26fb

serverStatus after third query (copy of the first, expected to be quick, but slow):  https://gist.github.com/crystalbit/aff0381bf6b3f9ed35674ecb9f3ca1a1

Comment: Have you tried checking your mongo status after each query using [`serverStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/)? Adding these information to your question can help others finding a solution.

Comment: You have `sort(_id:-1)`, which would affect the query planner and how indexes are used. I suspect the fast-slow-fast pattern you see is due to MongoDB having to replace the cache's content, since the second query implies a collections scan. Try to do `db.collection.explain('executionStats').find(...)` in the `mongo` shell and post the output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases try to cache frequent queries, or frequently accessed datasets. Of course such 'adaptiveness' results in different timing for the same queries, since the cache is finite and may be overwritten with fresh data.
In some databases you have more control over the process, in some less.
MongoDB provides some control, but it looks like it relies more on OS caching.
[FAQ: MongoDB Fundamental](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching)

Here is an example of explicit caching (look at the 'Fetching Categories' part).
[Refactoring Tornado Code With gen.engine](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-code-with-gen-engine/)